# Rename table with a strange name

Tags: mysql, rename

I have attempted to install an extenxion in Joomla, but there was a problem with the installation and the name of the tables are really weird.  The name is like `#__table1`.

I have problems because of "#" character.  I have tried with something like this, it doesn't work.  How should I proceed?

```
RENAME TABLE CHAR(35) + '__table1' TO xxxxx_table1, CHAR(35) + '__table2' TO xxxxx_table2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just using backticks:

```
RENAME TABLE `#__table1` to xxxxx_table1, `#__table2` to xxxxx_table2;
```

I did not test the `RENAME` command explicitly, but it seems possible to have a table name with a `#` sign, so long as we put backticks around the table name.

Side note, as you probably already figured out, you should avoid table and column names with strange symbols, or MySQL reserved keywords.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you!  Only one thing:  You forgot to write `RENAME TABLE`